# Remove automatic table headline

Tags: tables, captions

I use LaTeX for creating PDF output from R - not to create long documents. Hence the automatic `Table 1: <caption>` above the table is rather annoying. How can I remove the automatically generated `Table 1:`? Is it at all possible?

Comment: Maybe you could include some more information on how you generate your document? Do you use the `xtable` package, or Sweave, or do you export the data from R into a CSV file that you then import into LaTeX?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `caption` package with the `labelformat=empty` option:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage[labelformat=empty]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lll}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
a & b & c
\end{tabular}
\caption{Some super-secret data.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick, as sometimes the caption package does not cooperate:

```
\makeatletter
%You may (un-)comment this line to improve the looks.
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{{\csname the#1\endcsname}.\hspace{0.5em}} 

%Here is the crucial part:
\long\def\@maketblcaption#1#2{
}
\renewcommand{\table}{\let\@makecaption\@maketblcaption\@float{table}}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 0):

In the standard document class ([`article`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/article.cls), [`book`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/book.cls) and [`report`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/report.cls)), `\@makecaption` actually prints the float caption based on two arguments: The first is the float type (`\@captype`) and the second is the actual caption. If the removal of the float-specific addition is general (that is, for `table`, `figure` and others), then a redefinition of `\@makecaption` would suffice:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
% Taken from http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/article.cls
\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
  \vskip\abovecaptionskip
  \sbox\@tempboxa{#2}% \sbox{\@tempboxa{#1: #2}
  \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize
    #2\par% #1: #2\par
  \else
    \global \@minipagefalse
    \hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
  \fi
  \vskip\belowcaptionskip}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{lll}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    a & b & c
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Some super-secret data.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

In the above redefinition, the first argument `#1` is still read, but not used, and therefore removed from the caption.